# Add sum to specific row values based on filter of other rows while considering month groupings

Tags: r, dplyr

If I use group by in the below output I am getting an error that column 3 doesn't exist - I have determine it's because when I `group_by(person,month,revenue)` I do not get a return of any results.

The sample:

```
df <- structure(list(person = c("a", "a", 
                             "a", "a", "a", "b", 
                             "b", "b", "b", "b", 
                             "c", "c", "c", "c", 
                             "c", "c", "d", "d", 
                             "d", "d", "d"), report_month = c("01/01/2023", "02/01/2023", "03/01/2023", "11/01/2022", "12/01/2022", "01/01/2023", 
                                                              "02/01/2023", "03/01/2023", "11/01/2022", "12/01/2022", "03/01/2023", 
                                                              "01/01/2023", "02/01/2023", "03/01/2023", "11/01/2022", "12/01/2022", 
                                                              "01/01/2023", "02/01/2023", "03/01/2023", "11/01/2022", "12/01/2022"
                             ), revenue = c(-100, -805, -70, -26, 
                                                 -144, 77, 129, 10, 638, 898, -178.3, 
                                                 -133, -162, 2365, -480, -24, -393, 
                                                 -2088, -73, -41940, -25)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -21L))

# What I can do but adds the sum of a,b,c,d for all months to person 'b' where I need person 'b' to get the sum for their row by month the summarization is grouped in
# If I run group by after the filter I cannot accomplish this as each row is a unique grouping as I have to group by all attributes

df %>% 
  rows_update(
    data.frame(person = "b",
               df %>% 
                 filter(grepl('a|b|c|d',person,ignore.case = T)) %>%
                 summarise(across(c(3), sum))
    ),
    by = "person")
```

How can I

```
df %>% 
  rows_update(
    data.frame(person = "b",
               df %>% 
                 filter(grepl('a|b|c|d',person,ignore.case = T)) %>%
                 summarise(across(c(3), sum))
    ),
    by = "person")
```

and have it set up so that my output is:

````
```
person   month   total
a             1  original value
a             2  original value 
a             3  original value
a             4  original value
a             5  original value
b             1  sum of all for this month
b             2  sum of all for this month
b             3  sum of all for this month
b             4  sum of all for this month
b             5  sum of all for this month
```
````

The above works fine when only considering one month of values - but when each variable appears in multiple months and I want b to get the total values for all variables for that specific month - my group by breaks. Currently the output will show what it is if you plug this in. Person 'b' gets the sum of all for all months. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to sum all revenues for each person and month?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- structure(list(person = c("a", "a", 
                                "a", "a", "a", "b", 
                                "b", "b", "b", "b", 
                                "c", "c", "c", "c", 
                                "c", "c", "d", "d", 
                                "d", "d", "d"), report_month = c("01/01/2023", "02/01/2023", "03/01/2023", "11/01/2022", "12/01/2022", "01/01/2023", 
                                                                 "02/01/2023", "03/01/2023", "11/01/2022", "12/01/2022", "03/01/2023", 
                                                                 "01/01/2023", "02/01/2023", "03/01/2023", "11/01/2022", "12/01/2022", 
                                                                 "01/01/2023", "02/01/2023", "03/01/2023", "11/01/2022", "12/01/2022"
                                ), revenue = c(-100, -805, -70, -26, 
                                               -144, 77, 129, 10, 638, 898, -178.3, 
                                               -133, -162, 2365, -480, -24, -393, 
                                               -2088, -73, -41940, -25)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -21L))

df |> 
  mutate(month = month(dmy(report_month))) |> 
  summarize(revenue = sum(revenue),
            .by = c(person, month))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   person month revenue
#>   <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 a          1  -1145 
#> 2 b          1   1752 
#> 3 c          1   1388.
#> 4 d          1 -44519
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>